# Jquery - Closest value and replace the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple forms where once a user has finished completing the form ,they click on "continue" which then moves onto another part.. A heading at top of the page appears to show that the previous form has been completed.

If the heading at the top is clicked, it expands that particular form back open to let the person edit it. For example, if "FORM 1" has been completed and they are on "FORM 4" and realise in "FORM 1" that they had made a mistake then they can click and expand on this.

I want to be able to, when a user clicks on any given form heading then it basically hides the form that they are on, expands the form they wish to visit again and adds a "step" which is given by the ID of the form that they still are on.

I have used the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.continue').click(function() {
    var theID = $(this).attr('next-value');
    if (theID == 2) {
      $("#form-1").slideUp().addClass('hidden-form');
      $("#initialFormHeading").show();
      $("#form-2").show();
    }
  });

  $('.form-heading').click(function() {
    var theForm = $(this).attr('id');
    if (theForm == "initialFormHeading") {
      $("#form-1").show();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-heading" id="initialFormHeading" style="display:none">
    <h2>
        FORM 1 HEADING
      </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="form-1">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="NAME" />
    <br />
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="EMAIL" />
    <br />
    <a class="btn continue" current-value="1" next-value="2">CONTINUE</a>
  </div>

  <div id="form-2" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-heading" id="secondForm" style="display:none;">
      <h2>
             FORM 2
         </h2>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" />
    <br />
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="PO BOX" />
    <a class="btn continue" current-value="2" next-value="3">CONTINUE</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Currently both forms are showing. I have tried:

On the `continue` button for each of the divs which contains the form elements, there is a `current-value` and `next-value` I was aiming for so that when a user clicks on the form heading, it finds the nearest "continue" grabs the current value and then I can hide the form that way.

```
var x = $(this).next().find('.continue').attr('current-value');
```

However this does not work and shows undefined. I'm also open to other ways of how this can be done.

Comment: Like @Santi suggested: `$('.myFormsCommonClass').not(this).hide()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a class on all of the form divs. Inside your `form-heading` click function, hide all forms with that class. Then, on the next line, use your logic to show the form that was clicked on.

I've added the common class `formDiv` to all of your form divs and added the simple line `$(".formDiv").not(this).hide();` into your `.click` function to replicate the behavior I suggested above.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.continue').click(function() {
        var theID = $(this).attr('next-value');
        if (theID == 2) {
            $("#form-1").slideUp().addClass('hidden-form');
            $("#initialFormHeading").show();
            $("#form-2").show();
        }
    });

    $('.form-heading').click(function() {
        $(".formDiv").not(this).hide();
        var theForm = $(this).attr('id');
        if (theForm == "initialFormHeading") {
            $("#form-1").show();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-heading" id="initialFormHeading" style="display:none">
    <h2>
        FORM 1 HEADING
      </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="form-1" class="formDiv">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="NAME" />
    <br />
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="EMAIL" />
    <br />
    <a class="btn continue" current-value="1" next-value="2">CONTINUE</a>
  </div>

  <div id="form-2" class="formDiv" style="display:none;">
    <div class="form-heading" id="secondForm" style="display:none;">
      <h2>
             FORM 2
         </h2>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" />
    <br />
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="PO BOX" />
    <a class="btn continue" current-value="2" next-value="3">CONTINUE</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this:

```
var x = $(this).next().find('.continue').attr('current-value');
```

To this:(if you want to click the div that contains h2)

```
var x = $(this).parent().find('.continue').attr('current-value');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  window.steps = parseInt($('fieldset').length);
  $('fieldset').hide();
  $($('fieldset')[step - 1]).show();

  $('[data-step=prev]').click(function() {

    if (window.step > 1) {
      window.step--;
      $('fieldset').hide();
      $($('fieldset')[window.step - 1]).show();
    }
    if (window.step == 1) {
      $(this).prop('disabled', true)
    } else {
      $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (window.step == window.steps) {
      $('[data-step=next]').text('Submit')
    } else {
      $('[data-step=next]').text('Next');
    }
  });

  $('[data-step=next]').click(function() {

    if (window.step < window.steps) {
      window.step++;
      $('fieldset').hide();
      $($('fieldset')[window.step - 1]).show();
    }
    if (window.step == 1) {
      $('[data-step=prev]').prop('disabled', true)
    } else {
      $('[data-step=prev]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    if (window.step == window.steps) {
      $(this).text('Submit')
    } else {
      $(this).text('Next');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>FORM 1</legend>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
  <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>FORM 2</legend>
  <input type="text" name="pno" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" />
  <input type="text" name="pbox" value="" placeholder="Post box number" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>FORM 3</legend>
  <input type="text" name="city" value="" placeholder="City" />
  <input type="text" name="state" value="" placeholder="State" />
</fieldset>
<button data-step="prev" disabled>Previous</button>
<button data-step="next">Next</button>
<script>
  var step = 1;
  var steps;
</script>
```